# problem with conditions in javascript while working with DOM

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, conditional-statements

This condition is not working. When I click, it should hide all li elements and when I click again it should show all the li elements that are hidden but its not working

```
hide.addEventListener("click", function() {

        Array.from(list.children).forEach(function(k){

            if(k.style.display === "block") {
                k.style.display = "none";
                hide.textContent = "Show";
                list.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 33%)";
                list.style.borderRadius = "8px";
                document.querySelector(".hidden").style.display = "block";
                input.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
            } 

            else if (k.style.display === "none") {
                hide.textContent = "Hide";
                k.style.display = "block";
                list.style.backgroundColor == "transparent";
                list.style.borderRadius = "";
                document.querySelector(".hidden").style.display = "none";
                input.removeAttribute("disabled");
            } 

            else {

            };

        })
    });
```

Comment: Remember, `=` != `===`

Comment: toggling a class would be so much easier....

Comment: Actually, your `if` conditions are *not* working, in very subtle ways.  Assignment is not a test for equality.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Array.from(list.children).forEach(function(k){

    if(k.style.display == "block") {
        k.style.display = "none";
        hide.textContent = "Show";
        list.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 33%)";
        list.style.borderRadius = "8px";
        document.querySelector(".hidden").style.display = "block";
        input.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
    } 

    else if (k.style.display == "none") {
        hide.textContent = "Hide";
        k.style.display = "block";
        list.style.backgroundColor == "transparent";
        list.style.borderRadius = "";
        document.querySelector(".hidden").style.display = "none";
        input.removeAttribute("disabled");
    } 

    else {

    };

});
```

When you're trying to compare two values remember to use `==` or `===` instead of `=`. When you use `=` it means your ***DECLARING*** a value for something, whereas when you use `==` or `===` it means your ***COMPARING*** two values of something. Use `===` only when you want to be truly precise, for example `1 == '1'` would be true, whereas `1 === '1'` would be false as one is an integer and one is a string so they are not precisely the same.

Also the nice thing about JQuery is that you can use lots of its inbuilt functions to ***toggle*** certain things, in this case you could use .toggleClass() and have the same effect:

```
Array.from(list.children).forEach(function(k){

k.toggleClass('hidden');

});
```

And then in your CSS you could have:

```
.hidden {
display = 'block';
}
```